# How Can I Create Tentity Type For Genericrepository, With String Name?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-framework-version

Here I Made Generic Repository Class, I have the name of my 'TEntity' And I want to Access my model(Class) With that name

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> : IService<T>,IDisposable where T : class
```

This Is my Genericrepository

I have String 'Customers'
How Can I Convert this to access my model??

```
string model = "Customers";
// Convert String To TEntity Type.
GenericRepository<Customers> ctx = new GenericRepository<Customers>()
```

My Error IS '"model" is variable but is used Like type'

```
Type repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>).MakeGenericType(model);
var repository = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [`Type.GetType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.gettype?view=net-7.0#system-type-gettype(system-string)):

```cs
var modelType = Type.GetType("Customers");
Type repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>).MakeGenericType(modelType);
```

Though it may need the assembly-qualified type name:

> You can use the `GetType` method to obtain a `Type` object for a type in another assembly if you know its assembly-qualified name, which can be obtained from `AssemblyQualifiedName`. `GetType` causes loading of the assembly specified in `typeName`.

Notes:

1. I would recommend to just create a static dictionary from string to type for this goal, i.e.:

   ```cs
   public static class TypeHelper
   {
       public static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Type> Map = new Dictionary<string, Type>
       {
           { nameof(Customers), typeof(Customers) }
       };
   }
   ```
2. Generic repository/UoW over EF can be considered an [antipattern](https://bigmachine.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/) (if you are using EF).
3. I would argue that you should think twice before using runtime construction via reflection.